# unable to deploy war file to wildfly using jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-plugins, wildfly

I'm trying to configure a local instance of jenkins to automate the deployment.
I'm using wildfly 8.2.1.Final, and WildFly Deployer Plugin in jenkins.

When I configure my project to deploy my war file to wildfly from jenkins i get the following errors:

Connected to WildFly at localhost:9990
Deploying target\TalonPTC.war ...

```
FATAL: {"outcome" => "failed","result" => {"step-1" => {"outcome" => "failed","rolled-back" => true},"step-2" => {"outcome" => "failed","failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./TalonPTC" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./TalonPTC: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\\Servers\\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\\standalone\\tmp\\vfs\\temp\\tempace3ce2e6837e151\\content-b79b5d3553132017\\content-2285857293233879332.tmp (Access is denied)

...
... (many more errors)
...

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\\Servers\\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\\standalone\\tmp\\vfs\\temp\\tempace3ce2e6837e151\\content-b79b5d3553132017\\content-2285857293233879332.tmp (Access is denied)"}}}},"rolled-back" => true}
```

Build step 'Deploy WAR/EAR to WildFly' marked build as failure

Comment: Yes. But how would I be able to grant the access. I have configured the jenkins with credentials to admin console. and it is able to connect as well. But unable to transfer and deploy.

Comment: How often does it happen? Also feel free to comment on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1548

Comment: The file might be open.

Comment: It happens all the time, apart from starting the server i'm not accessing any files.